# How do I configure fzf to return only a specific field of the selected line?

Tags: shell

I recently ran into [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf), which seems like a fantastic little tool, but there's one thing I'm having trouble with: given input with multiple fields per line, how do I configure it to return only a particular field when pressing `enter`? The `accept` action, which is the default binding for the `enter` key, doesn't accept any parameters...you can't use `--bind enter:accept(1)` or something like that.

The `--nth` and `--with-nth` options affect which fields are searched (`--nth`) or displayed (`--with-nth`), but don't impact what gets returned.

For example, if I run a command like:

```
ps -fe | fzf --some-options...
```

I'd like pressing `enter` on a line that looks like this:

```
  root        2067       1  0 08:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/gdm
```

To emit only `2067` on stdout.

Is the only option to post-process the output from `fzf` with another tool (e.g., `awk`)?

Answer (score 11):

```shell
ps -fe | fzf --bind 'enter:execute(echo {2})+abort'
```

That gives you the second field

or for multiselection:

```shell
ps -fe | fzf -m --bind 'enter:execute(echo {+2})+abort'
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer by [testoflow](https://superuser.com/users/1207374/testoflow) gave me a very good hint, and I got to find out a solution using `become()`.

```sh
ps -fe | fzf --bind 'enter:become(echo {2})'
```

```sh
ps -fe | fzf -m --bind 'enter:become(echo {+2})'
```